# control servo using android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, servo

Asked question master, how to coding in arduino for controlling servo using android via bluetooth? Code below does not work, servo only runs between 48 - 56.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> #include <SoftwareSerial.h> #include <Servo.h> Servo servo; int bluetoothTx = 10; int bluetoothRx = 11; SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx); void setup() {   servo.attach(9);
 Serial.begin(9600); bluetooth.begin(9600);} void loop() {
//read from bluetooth and wrtite to usb serial
if(bluetooth.available()> 0 ){    int servopos = bluetooth.read();
Serial.println(servopos);
servo.write(servopos);}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the data as string using: `string input = bluetooth.readString();`
2. Then convert string to int using: `int servopos = int(input);`
3. Then write the position to the servo:`servo.write(servopos);`

Now depending on the data you send from android, you could need to :
Trim it: `input = input.trim();`
Or constrain it : `servopos = constrain(servopos,0,180);`

Your corrected code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;
int bluetoothTx = 10;
int bluetoothRx = 11;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);
void setup() {
  servo.attach(9);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  bluetooth.begin(9600);
} 

void loop() {
  //read from bluetooth and wrtite to usb serial
  if (bluetooth.available() > 0 ) {
    String s = bluetooth.readString();
    s.trim();
    float servopos = s.toFloat();
    servopos = constrain(servopos, 0, 180);
    Serial.println("Angle: "+String(servopos));
    servo.write(servopos);
  }
}
```

Comment: How to write it in arduino code? I'm a beginner. May I copy your program ? @Wadaane

Comment: Ok, I'll post it later.

Comment: Done, now try it, and if there is an issue let me know. Please up vote my answer and comments, if you found them helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What you are reading from the bluetooth is coming in as individual bytes of ascii code.  The ascii codes for digits run from 48 to 57.  So if you send for example "10" then it sends a 49 and then a 48.  You are just reading the values directly.  Instead you need to accumulate the characters you read into a buffer until you have them all and then use atoi to convert to a real number you can use.