# Convert ASCII to Int

Tags: arduino, ascii

I'm using an Arduino for a project that involves controlling a servo via the serial monitor. The Arduino was receiving different values than what I entered. I'm sure that this is because serial data is read as ASCII. Is there any way that I could convert it to Int? Thanks!

Comment: What language?  Most have a string-to-int function of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by Arduino you mean "Arduino IDE (C++)".

Arduino has a `toInt()` function.

```
int asciiVal = 97;
String mystr = (char)asciiVal;
Serial.println(mystr);             //prints a
Serial.println(mystr.toInt());     //prints 97
```

Explained here:  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringToIntExample

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:
`string input = Serial.readString();
int angle = int(input);`

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44402203/7158464).